# Jetty: Idle timeout expired exception on JSON deserialization in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring, jackson, jetty

I see occasional stack traces like the following when the Spring Boot 2.0 server handles an incoming request. I am using Spring Boot 2.2.4 with spring-boot-starter-jetty. This exception only happens around 0.1% of time. Has anyone seen something similar and has any idea on why this would happen? The service is running in AWS EKS behind an Application Load Balancer.

```
j.u.c.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
    at o.e.j.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
    at o.e.j.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
    at j.u.c.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at j.u.c.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at j.u.c.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at j.u.c.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at j.u.c.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HttpInput failure
        at o.e.j.s.HttpInput.failed(HttpInput.java:830)
        at o.e.j.s.HttpConnection$BlockingReadCallback.failed(HttpConnection.java:656)
        at o.e.j.i.FillInterest.onFail(FillInterest.java:138)
        at o.e.j.i.AbstractEndPoint.onIdleExpired(AbstractEndPoint.java:407)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
    at o.e.j.s.HttpInput$ErrorState.noContent(HttpInput.java:1083)
    at o.e.j.s.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:321)
    at c.r.p.e.s.c.s.MeasurableRequestWrapper$CountingInputStream.read(MeasurableRequestWrapper.java:62)
    at j.i.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at j.i.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:183)
    at c.f.j.c.j.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:220)
    at c.f.j.c.j.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseEscapedName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1985)
    at c.f.j.c.j.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseLongName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1872)
    at c.f.j.c.j.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseMediumName2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1810)
    at c.f.j.c.j.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseMediumName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1767)
    at c.f.j.c.j.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1702)
    at c.f.j.c.j.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1029)
    at c.f.j.d.d.s.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:512)
    at c.f.j.d.d.s.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at c.f.j.d.d.s.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at c.f.j.d.d.s.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286)
    ... 124 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: c.f.j.d.JsonMappingException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms (through reference chain: com.abc.service.api.resources.SalesDataRequest["details"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.abc.service.api.resources.SalesDataRequest$SalesDataDetail["events"]->java.util.ArrayList[2])
    at c.f.j.d.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at c.f.j.d.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:365)
    at c.f.j.d.d.s.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer...
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, it is way how to reproduce it locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a connection that was supplying data on the request body (hence the `HttpInput` references).

The data was in a blocking read (`HttpInput.read()`) waiting for more data.

Then the idle time out kicked in for that connection and the read was failed with `HttpInput.noContent()` indicating that the read was incomplete, with a nested cause of Idle Timeout.

This is a standard idle timeout scenario.

Not that unusual or remarkable.

Quite common with mobile clients (mobile tower switch, poor network connectivity, switching from cell tower to wifi, or back again, etc).  It even happens with browsers on laptops (wifi issues, browser crashes, battery issues, lid closed, sleep mode, etc..)

The fact that it happens with only 1% of your requests is actually quite remarkable (usually the percentage of requests with network issues is higher on a public facing web site)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it make sense to increase the timeout from 30 seconds? Also, which status code should be returned in this case?

Comment: Idle timeout results in a hard close.  There's usually no status codes returned (as the cause is usually a network issue).  30 seconds is already quite high.  Making the idle timeout longer isn't really going to change anything for those problematic clients.  It will just mean you have dead network connections active and in "in use" by the server for no good reason, starving other good requests for server resources.

Comment: I got this same error, but in my case it's an aws lambda function that makes the call